# SharePoint Term Store and Managed MetaData (BCS?)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

From a high and low level, how do i acomplish the following with using Term Store and Managed MetaData.

I have the following fields:

CustomerID
CustomerName
CustomerDescription

I would like to expect that if i go into add a new item in a new list that is using this managed metadata property that there is a way that I can select from a drop down the customer name and automatically have filled out the customer ID, Name, and Description.

My questions:

1. If this is possible out of the box, how can it be done, can you please guide me into the right direction?
2. If it can't be done out of the box, how can it be done?  I would assume that I would need to add custom code somewhere, but if so where?

It is important that I have someone that can help me out with this as it is a tough item to research.

Bill.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is supported out of the box.  When I initially read your post I thought maybe you could created a content type and use calculated fields based off of the Customer Name field, but that does not seem possibly as per this [article](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/06/managed-metadata-column-limitations/) and it looks like info path forms are off the table as well.

There might be some work arounds such as creating a custom dialog based off a custom visual web part or application page that is launched via the ribbon.  The web part/application page could be programmed to handle the logic you are looking to achieve.  Another solution would be to create 2 web parts, 1 for the list and another for adding items and managing the whole element through code.  It's hard to give direction without knowing what kind of items the list will contain (simple data, files, etc).